# Re-naming multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename, batch-rename

I have multiple directories inside which there are multiple files.

In directory1 files have the name format:

1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.124.27456-3-**1**-10jd0au.dcm

1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.124.27456-3-**2**-10jd0av.dcm

....

1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.124.27456-3-**10**-17v7m18.dcm

In directory2:

1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.46.34440-4-**1**-r3hu3u.dcm

1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.46.34440-4-**2**-r3hu3v.dcm

....

and so on.

How can I rename these as just **1.dcm**, **2.dcm**,.....in each directory?

My attempt is as follows:

```
for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(dir_path):
    for dname in dnames:
        directory = os.path.join(dir_path,dname)
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            old_name = os.path.join(directory,filename)
            new = filename[filename.find("-"):]
            new_name = os.path.join(directory, new)
            os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

But this only yields:

-3-1-10jd0au.dcm

-3-10-17v7m18.dcm

Comment: You could use a regex like `".*-.*-(.*)-.*(\..*)"gm` to capture the parts you want - the number will be in the first group and the file extension in the second group. Or you could split the string on the `-` character and use the appropriate item from the resulting list, and handle the extension separately.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant. Could you please clarify with an example?

Comment: Oh I understood it. I think I will be able to do it by splitting the string. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that uses a regex to extract the parts of the filename that you need, for example:

```
import re

def ExtractNumber(filename):
  parts = re.search(r".*-.*-(.*)-.*(\..*)", filename)
  return parts.group(1) + parts.group(2)

print(ExtractNumber("1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.124.27456-3-1-10jd0au.dcm"))
print(ExtractNumber("1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.133.1.3.49.1.124.27456-3-10-17v7m18.dcm"))
```

Outputs:

```
1.dcm
10.dcm
```